# Matplotlib.axes.Axes.bar conditional formatting

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart

I have a vertical bar plot in matplotlib and would like the color of the bars to vary based on the values in an array. I know that in plot.scatter() this can be done with cmap=''. But i can't seem to find the same functionality with plot.bar(). Any advice? [image: here] is the figure in question.

```
fig, season = plt.subplots()

# show the phenology season

season.set_ylabel('GPP 20th percent yearly max')
season.tick_params('y', colors = 'blue', labelsize =24)

season.bar(x = pheno['SRO_SoS'], height= pheno['SRO_20th'], width = 
           pheno['SRO_DateDelta'], zorder=1, color = 'wheat', align = 
'edge')

season.set_ylim(0,5)
temp = season.twinx()

temp.plot(df_w.index, df_w['TA_F'],color = 'red', label = 'Tempurature', 
linewidth = 2)

# set x-label 
temp.set_xlabel('Date')
temp.tick_params('x', labelsize =24)

 # set primary y label
temp.set_ylabel('Tempurature (C)')
temp.tick_params('y', colors = 'red', labelsize =24)

# set x-axis limits as the min and max of the series
temp.set_xlim(date2num([df_w.index.min(), df_w.index.max()]))
temp.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%d-%m-%Y'))
temp.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.YearLocator(1, month=1, day=1))

temp.set_ylim(2,30)

temp.grid(True)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give an array to the color argument in your `season.bar()`. That should work.

If you want to give discrete colors, here is an example.

```
fig, season = plt.subplots()
clist = ['red', 'blue', 'green']
season.bar(x = range(1, 11), height= range(10, 30, 2), width = 0.8, zorder=1, color = clist, align = 'edge')
```

**Discrete colors - Output plot**

[image]

For using cmap continuous colors, here is another example.

```
fig, season = plt.subplots()
my_cmap = plt.get_cmap("viridis")
colorrange = [0,0.25,0.5,0.75,1.0] #Range should be in range of 0 to 1
season.bar(x = range(1, 11), height= range(10, 30, 2), width = 0.8, zorder=1, color=my_cmap(colorrange), align = 'edge')
```

**Continuous colors - Output plot**

[image]

Comment: This worked well in my code, thank you! Is there anyway I can make the colors depended on values in an array. if i have values betwen 1-365, would i have to normalize them between 0-1 and then use those normalized values in the colorrange list?

Comment: Yes, normalizing is required. You can check the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64068659/bar-chart-in-matplotlib-using-a-colormap) - using lambda, you can have continuous colors - it also normalizes the values